# Trying to customize my radio button but nothing will change

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to change the checked button to a different color. I don't have a `checked` attribute because I am map through an object to display value. I have tried targeting the input tag but nothing seems to work. I also want to be able to change color when hovering but I have had no luck with that either.

Here is my css:

```
.radio-btn {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.radio-btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Here is the button file:

```
import React from "react";

const EyewearPurchaseBtn = (props) => (
    <div>
        <form className="eyewear-purchase-form" onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <h3>Select Size</h3>

                    {
                        props.sizes.map( size => (
                            <div key={size} >
                            <input onChange={props.handleChange} className="radio-btn" type="radio" name="purchaseVal" value={size} />
                            <label className="eyewear-purchase-label">{size}</label><br/>   
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }

                    <button className="buy-now">Buy Now</button>    
                </form>
    </div>
);

export default EyewearPurchaseBtn;
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? You can't add CSS to radio that way. You are changing the bg colour of input element but it has a radio button so you don't see any change. If you want your data to be checked map provides the second argument as index which might help you set which one is checked

Comment: It being checked isn't a problem I am able to do that. I just want to change the default color of blue to a different color like black.

Comment: you can't modify the input buttons as such. what you can position your input absolutely, make opacity 0 and add your custom CSS replicating that. You can also use a good css framework

Comment: w3schools has a tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is exactly what your are looking for, but you can create fake radio button with css. Here is an example :

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

label { position: relative; }

label:before, label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

label:before {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #3b3a39;
  left: -20px;
}

label:after {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #f0e9e9;
  left: -16px;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after { opacity: 1; }
input[type="radio"]:hover + label:before { background-color: #74706c; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="purchaseVal" checked />
  <label>Label 1</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="purchaseVal" />
  <label>Label 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that I don't have a `checked` attribute. I'm mapping do it would at it to all buttons and all would initially be checked. Otherwise this would totally work!